# What is the Python command to check if current view is in orthographic or perspective mode?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, orthographic

What is the python command to check if current view is in orthographic or perspective mode?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: No effort... @Pullup

Comment: @Pullup People playing as God ? judging other people by their standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`Region3D.view_perspective`**.

Get the space data of the 3D view area. A screen is split up into areas. The space associated with area is the active space.  The spaces 3d region has the view settings.

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'VIEW_3D')
(3, 'TEXT_EDITOR')

>>> space = C.screen.areas[2].spaces.active
```

If we are sure we are in a 3d view (a panel there, an operator that polls there) then instead use

```
space = context.space_data
```

the property to change is `view_perspective`, in example below I am in perspective view

```
>>> space.region_3d.view_perspective
'PERSP'
```

Tip A quick way to find the options available is crunch in something wrong.

```
>>> space.region_3d.view_perspective = 'FOO'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "FOO" not found in ('PERSP', 'ORTHO', 'CAMERA')
```

Check if in ortho view.  *Could also check if in camera view, is camera ortho*

```
>>> ortho_view = space.region_3d.view_perspective == 'ORTHO'
```

or perhaps (needs testing)

```
>>> ortho_view = not space.region_3d.is_perspective
```

Set to ortho

```
>>> space.region_3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'
```