# Specify Ortho View instead of Toggling

Tags: python, 3d-view, add-on

View > Perspective/Orthographic (Numpad 5) allows you to toggle between them. I'd like to specify Ortho without toggling, using python.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def execute(self, context):
    # Switch to orthographic view
    bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='RIGHT')
    bpy.ops.view3d.view_perspective(type='ORTHO')
```

Which doesn't entirely work. I was checking out this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181110/what-is-the-python-command-to-check-if-current-view-is-in-orthographic-or-perspe), and I'm unable to get the recommendation for setting to Ortho to work either:

```
space.region_3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'
```

I get a space needs to be defined error, but I don't know if that's exactly what I need anyways. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

print ("started")

for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
    print(a.type)
    if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
       
        space = a.spaces.active
        space.region_3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'
        print("set ortho")
```

Comment: Thank you. How is this being placed, is it inside the class but outside of any functions? It seems to only want to break the pie menu when I try on my end.

Comment: I just run that script in my text editor - can u verify that this works in your Texteditor?

Comment: It does work running on it's own in the text editor, yes.

Comment: And from where, or how do you want to trigger this?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, thank you for the response. I'm wanting to trigger this via a button on a pie menu.